# Reading very large .xml.bz2 files

Tags: c#, xml

I'd like to parse Wikimedia's .xml.bzip2 dumps without extracting the entire file or performing any XML validation:

```
var filename = "enwiki-20160820-pages-articles.xml.bz2";

var settings = new XmlReaderSettings()
{
    ValidationType = ValidationType.None,
    ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto // Fragment ?
};

using (var stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
using (var bz2 = new BZip2InputStream(stream))
using (var xml = XmlTextReader.Create(bz2, settings))
{
    xml.ReadToFollowing("page");
    // ...
}
```

The `BZip2InputStream` works - if I use a `StreamReader`, I can read XML line by line. But when I use `XmlTextReader`, it fails when I try to perform the read:

> System.Xml.XmlException: 'Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: mediawiki. Line 58, position 1.'

The bzip stream is *not* at EOF. Is it possible to open an XmlTextReader on top of a BZip2 stream? Or is there some other means to do this?

Comment: The files are zip files (gz) and the gz contains a single article.  If the gz contained multiple files then you could read the index and extract a single file.  Since the gz contains a single file you have to download the entire file and extract before you can parse the xml data.

Comment: "Very large" is meaningless: it can mean anything from 1Mb to 1Tb. If you can't give us a number, then don't bother mentioning the size.

Comment: @jdweng - this dump is a single, very large XML file containing all of Wikipedia - not a tarball of individual files.

Comment: I'm not seeing any dump file(s) at website in xml format.  All the dumps are in other formats.  These files may contain xml format but the extensions of the file are different which indicates XmlTextRead cannot be used.

Comment: @MichaelKay As stated, the file is a `.xml.bz2` dump of English Wikipedia. It should be evident that it's at least in the gigabytes range. To be precise, though, it's 12.3GB compressed.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  I used combination of XmlReader and Xml Linq.  You can parse the XElement doc as needed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;


namespace ConsoleApplication29
{
    class Program
    {
        const string URL = @"https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20160820/enwiki-20160820-abstract26.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(URL);

            while (!reader.EOF)
            {
                if (reader.Name != "doc")
                {
                    reader.ReadToFollowing("doc");
                }
                if (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    XElement doc = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, though this still uses the XML input file, not the compressed XML. I can use basically this code on my local file when I decompress, but wrapping the BZip2InputStream with an XmlReader still throws the same exception.

Comment: When I downloaded the file earlier I could not read file directly into chrome.  I had to save file to disk.  I'm wondering if you ftp the file to disk before opening if you get same error.  I did not try my code to read entire file from URL.  Wondering if same error occurs.