# Indexing a large XML file

Tags: c#, xml, performance, indexing, bigdata

Given a large (74GB) XML file, I need to read specific XML nodes by a given Alphanumeric ID. It takes too long to read from top-to-bottom of the file looking for the ID.

Is there an analogy of an Index for XML files like there is for relational databases?, I imagine a small Index file, where the Alphanumeric ID is quick to find, and points to the location in the larger file.

Do Index files for XML exist?, how can they be implemented in C#?

Comment: _"Given a large (74GB) XML file"_ - and nobody, nowhere during the development process or evaluation thereof, thought: _"Wait, isn't this file going to be a teensy bit on the large side, would XML actually be the correct storage format"_? Are you sure an index is going to solve the problem, won't you rather actually read the contents into an RDBMS?

Comment: ^^ what CodeCaster says + Or wouldn't it be more reasonable to not have _one_ giant XML file but many smaller ones? The first thing I (as a senior dev) would tell a junior dev when they told me "we have a 74GB XML file" is "Are you nuts? Let me talk to the person who came up with this ..."

Comment: @CodeCaster - Yes, reading the XML file into a database, and indexing the column on the database is an option. I was curious if there was an alternative.

Comment: @Fildor - That's another alternative. Currently running a batch to split the file into 10 million smaller XML files. It's been running for 48 hours non-stop :)

Comment: Reading it into an RDBMS is one thing. But how about avoiding that abomination in the first place? Handling a file of that size will always send you into some sort of hell.

Comment: 10 Million ... wow. One more reason to reconsider XML overall. Is that some sort of DB dump from a 3rd party system?

Comment: So, what I am saying is basically: This seems to be a X-Y-Problem. The thing is: A XML-File of that size is obviously a hazardous design choice. That said, you should rather not put your resources into figuring out how to handle it anyway but you rather should work towards finding a better alternative to that XML in the first place. But that would be a different question than the one posted. If - for whatever reason - you are not allowed to do that or this "interface" is set by 3rd party, I'd highly recommend to escalate that problem to your superiors, or you _will_ constantly run into walls.

Comment: it's terrible design,ok. But every senior dev knows (or should know) that sometimes this kind of requests come and you have to handle. So, just to be constructive, I'd prefer a nosqlDB instead of a RDBMS, XML->BSON will reduce size on disk and relations are not useful because we are talking of a single table.

Comment: I would expect that using Saxon XSLT 3.0 in streaming mode to split the document into many small documents would take about an hour.

Comment: With Huge xml files you must use XmlReader.  Best way is to loop through a repeating tag.  See my code at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944048/reading-very-large-xml-bz2-files?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML databases such as BaseX, eXistDB, or MarkLogic do what you are looking for: they load XML documents into a persistent form on disk and allow fast access to parts of the document by use of indexes.

Some XML databases are optimized for handling many small documents, others are able to handle a small number of large documents, so choose your product carefully (I can't advise you on this), and consider breaking the document up into smaller parts as it is loaded.

If you need to split the large document into lots of small documents, consider a streaming XSLT 3.0 processor such as Saxon-EE. I would expect that processing 75Gb should take about an hour: dependent, obviously, on the speed of your machine.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is beyond of the scope of what XML tries to achieve. If the XML does not change often and your read from it a lot, I would propose rewriting its content into a local SQLite DB once-per-change and then reading from the database instead. When doing the rewriting, remember that SAX-style XML reading is your friend in the case of huge files like this.

Theoretically, you can create a sort-of index by remembering location of already discovered IDs and then parse on your own, but that would be very brittle. XML si not simple enough for you to parse it on your own and hope you will be standard compliant.

Of course, I suppose here that you can't do anything with the larger design itself: as others noted, the size of that file suggests that there is an architectural problem.