# Using Protobuf vs JSON instead of XML in a C# program?

Tags: c#, json, xml, serialization, protobuf-net

In my company, we have a program that is reading from a device and writing saving the data into `XML` files which are styled with `XSLT` files and presented to the end user.

Everything was fine until the size of the data read became bigger and currently we are even planning to have much more data and `XML` will not be good enough to handle all this data.

Now we should adopt either `Protobuf` or `JSON` instead of `XML` to store data read from the device and also to store configuration files to be written to the device. The advantages of `Protobuf` for us are:

> 1 - Faster than `JSON`
>   2 - Smaller size

However some concerns were raised and we are looking for a solution to them:

> 1 - `Protobuf` files aren't editable as easy as `XML` & `JSON` as it is
>   stored in a binary format and it isn't human readable
>   2 - if the
>   structure of the data being read was updated for any reason (adding
>   more fields for example) will this affect the backward compatibility
>   to read the older files
>   3 - Is there a way to style `Protobuf` files like `XML` with `Xslt`

Comment: Is this your question: _"3- Is there a way to style protobuf files like Xml with Xslt"_ If so, you might want to make that more clear because it's buried in a lot of introductory text.

Comment: No my question whether I should use Protobuf or not with the associated givens

Comment: Well, that would highly depend on your own circumstances and ability to maintain the solution. Surely there are people using Protobuf and they have their reasons, so it's a question of whether it's right for you, which none of us can answer based on the information given. This question is highly subjective and not well suited for Stack Overflow based on the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). I suggest asking a more concrete, objective question.

Comment: Consider EXI as another option. I suspect it will give you all the same benefits as Protobuf, with the advantage that EXI has the same data model as XML and is therefore readily and losslessly convertible to XML, meaning that the change is much less disruptive to your existing toolchain.

Comment: For large XML files you should use the XmlReader() class in Net.  With XmlReader I normally read one section at a time using Xml Linq.  See my solution at following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40944048/reading-very-large-xml-bz2-files?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

1. Indeed, you wouldn't want to hand edit them; scripted editing through code should be fine, though
2. Adding fields is fully backwards compatible. As is removing fields. The protocol was designed with versioning in mind. What you can't do is change how an existing field is stored - some type changes are fine, some are immediately breaking, and some will silently break (unsigned to signed, for example)
3. Not directly; any common UI / data-binding API should work though